# Running a micro stepper motor by using arduino

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, motion

The link below provides the info of the motor that I want to use. I've seen some ICs like L293,SN75441 and a board called [EasyDriver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9402) are being used for driving the motor. Can the motor be microstepped by using both the ICs and the easy driver board? If so then do I have make any changes in the sketch? Can anyone suggest me the appropriate arduino board.

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9238

Comment: What are the characteristics of your stepper: voltage and current ratings, number of coils, and type (unipolar, bipolar)?

Comment: you can use rack and pinion to covert rotary movement to, to and pro movement

Comment: What do you mean when you say "micro" stepper motor? Do you mean micro-sized (e.g. small/tiny), or that you want to micro-step the motor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the motor be microstepped by using ... the easy driver board?

Yes.

Have you considered perhaps reading the [bildr EasyDriver tutorial](http://bildr.org/2011/06/easydriver/) on the page you linked to?

One of many ways to drive this motor is:

- Hook the 4 wires of this stepper motor to a [EasyDriver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10267) Stepper Motor Driver or one of the many other [stepper motor drivers](http://reprap.org/wiki/Stepper_motor_driver).
- Connect "motor power" to the stepper motor driver board -- to the "GND" and "M+" terminals -- 24 VDC is a common voltage compatible with this "12V" motor and this "30V" motor driver.
- Connect the "GND", "Step", and "Dir" pins of the EasyDriver (or other stepper motor driver) to the Arduino, or one of many other development boards.
- Use a USB cable to connect the Arduino to your development PC, powering the Arduino from the +5 VDC in the USB cable.
- Run some Arduino software, such as the example sketch, that pulses the "Step" pin and perhaps flips the "Dir" pin from Forward to Reverse occasionally.

By default, the EasyDriver already microsteps at 8x -- you'd have to ground M2 to get it to *not* microstep.

> ICs like L293,SN75441 ... Can the motor be microstepped by using both
>   the ICs and the easy driver board?

The EasyDriver does all the translation necessary between the "step, dir" signals from the Arduino and the motor wires. It doesn't need any other ICs.

> do I have make any changes in the sketch?

No, you don't have to make any changes to the sketch.
The sketch should work with any Arduino and any one of the many stepper motor drivers (linked above) with a "step, dir" interface.

> the appropriate arduino board.

Any Arduino board would work.

[Arduino Buying Guide](https://www.sparkfun.com/pages/arduino_guide)

Answer (score 0):

As per the usual, I would recommend the [Pololu A4988](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1182). It's super easy to set up and use, and you can microstep with it (all the way to a 1/16 step). It's also relatively cheap, uses a minimum of only two digital output pins (or one, if you don't need to change direction!), and can be operated very easily with Arduino.